# Loop reload same trial instead of next one Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, loops, reload, qualtrics

I have a problem with Qualtrics Loop and Merge + Javascript. Basically, Qualtrics reload the previous trial of my loop instead of a new one.

First, here is what I try to do: I have two sets of pictures, at each loop, one picture of each set is randomly picked and displayed (randomly to the left or right side). At the end of the loop, each pictures of the set will be displayed (33 in each set, so 33 trials of the loop), without picking twice the same picture. At each trial, I also display randomly the name of the condition "in relationship" or "friends"

The problem in details:
I have coded something that seems to work quite well, except at some point: It happens that when loading the next trial of the loop, it doesn't display new pictures but instead the one that were presented in the previous trial (and also the same name of condition). This can go for a while presenting me always the same pictures, or this can just be one time. 
In any case, this trial which is represented count as a trial, as my loop always ends after 33 trials, whatever if some of these are actually not new pictures presented. 
This problem doesn't appear always at the same trial, and can appear several times in a loop. 
It also happened that only one picture displayed is new, and the other is the one presented in the previous trial. (I really don't get how this can happen).
I coded the randomisation of picture in an empty question, just before the question where it displays the pictures. This empty question is supposed to not require to press the "next" button. When the trial are correct, this is working well, but when the next trial is going to be one "reloaded" trial, it requires to press the "next" button. 
I tried  the survey with Firefox and Edge, and the problem is the same.

My javascript code: 
In the first question of the survey:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function () {
    function shuffle(o) { //v1.0
        for (var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
        return o;
    };

    var FacesM_list = "IM_7U04c3TQlA7dT3D,IM_eE5iBcKfoOblbJH,IM_a3mklzA9E1OuRWl,IM_bQnoSJOGwa0vn9P,IM_5inNCVgPdHHTVSR,IM_bHlurQJWSXDRDFj,IM_3rCr2DIzW2cvqLP,IM_509x1wz7pM6PP0N,IM_3UGdsp02IcCqaSV,IM_eLrY7bwDPiT7apn,IM_3LdlHnBb6tnkBEh,IM_3pY6z6JDgaDvwq1,IM_9HtZxBS79DiOfR3,IM_03c9pDSpcwcqIyF,IM_6WGKJOzUWK4TJat,IM_2rxQPEGO7SEvsY5,IM_9YN3UCUtWEWTfGR,IM_8jZTSUAGJfuVECV,IM_9nQkFhRY2cLIVgN,IM_2abcJA7B79jt30h,IM_cD31N8XPTGliUN7,IM_0eL8iQd4PVdyuQl,IM_cuOoV9gSAe6CWd7,IM_9Nv3X7lWYEsTzsF,IM_5ccXAuuomEEyamp,IM_9mnvThFiNA5U84t,IM_e3UGNNuMdrKH8cl,IM_3aggsd5P9MMlUDr,IM_4ORY6GEMW8CmNPT,IM_50WOBkz8ADTFGHH,IM_3rqtlVBfijYCccZ,IM_3CzDsr0tYv7PH5H,IM_4SmeprjDgOeCl5b"
    var FacesF_list = "IM_6fkHDs5f6ItAuk5,IM_0ri9MLjDhHxyonP,IM_bKlHtoAaxnBFlnT,IM_1WUqtBPpdhERpjf,IM_ac0yWos8tAqSMNT,IM_3xCePACn1Lq97tH,IM_6o1ZPLGUM682Au1,IM_babATdN3VtBLIsl,IM_8HSUICLvFvDXaN7,IM_0ebTztq3ML5Zh0V,IM_3lB8j5dhMs8i8ip,IM_0iC0pwDlpOkcTGt,IM_cIRojwU6sx3W7Od,IM_9ZHNbignrAfcThX,IM_8iFXvVcCqk5hemN,IM_6rrwImdl4Nss0u1,IM_6mPEaoIdazwqAWp,IM_b8lrxhsPGcc1HaR,IM_23uYWeF2gYVMsap,IM_6ycfrm5xOlewjFb,IM_7UKValFGc9Kmpp3,IM_8Bbkzsmc7CyMvqt,IM_d5S95FnSgo8j06F,IM_brXT4VUU8QJiRwN,IM_9MEkpgEmOwXhril,IM_6KG9qokOlD16GDH,IM_ellgVnYbtb8ZSbb,IM_eg6qSYMQ56z5JpX,IM_5vfbDNPdZeP1XCZ,IM_cDbOprwCUUSnUZT,IM_cumIGHXOFByV4Pz,IM_0jh2Va4JTfGsQDz,IM_0CGlFRy4dW8lDcF"
    var FacesM_order = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 33; i++) {
        FacesM_order.push(i);
    }

    FacesM_order = shuffle(FacesM_order);
    var FacesF_order = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 33; i++) {
        FacesF_order.push(i);
    }
    FacesF_order = shuffle(FacesF_order);
    var nTrial = 0;

    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("FacesM_order", FacesM_order.toString());
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("FacesF_order", FacesF_order.toString());
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("FacesF_list", FacesF_list.toString());
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("FacesM_list", FacesM_list.toString());
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("nTrial", nTrial.toString());

});
```

And in the first question of the Block with Loop and Merge:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function () {
    var nTrial = Number("${e://Field/nTrial}") + 1;
    var FacesF_list = "${e://Field/FacesF_list}".split(',');
    var FacesM_list = "${e://Field/FacesM_list}".split(',');
    var FacesF_order = "${e://Field/FacesF_order}".split(',');
    var FacesM_order = "${e://Field/FacesM_order}".split(',');
    var FacesF = FacesF_list[FacesF_order[nTrial]];
    var FacesM = FacesM_list[FacesM_order[nTrial]];
    var rand = Math.random()

    if (rand < 0.5) {
        var left = FacesF
        var right = FacesM
    } else {
        var left = FacesM
        var right = FacesF
    }

    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("nTrial", nTrial.toString());
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("left", left.toString());
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("right", right.toString());

    this.clickNextButton.delay(.00000000000001);
});
```

Thanks a lot for your help!